# How to remove elements from a vector while iterating through

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector, and I need to compare every element and remove elements until only one remains. I have some loops to iterate through, but once I remove a few elements I get "Vector subscript out of range".
I imagine this is because I've deleted elements and am trying to iterate over empty space in the vector, but I thought my loop condition would handle it.

Basically I'm storing shapes, and remove shapes that are overlapping until one remains, shuffling the positions on the grid if none are overlapping. (assume the conditionmet() is correct)

```
while (shapeGrid.size() > 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < shapeGrid.size(); i++)
    {

        for (int x = 0; x < shapeGrid.size(); x++)
        {

            if (conditionmet())
            {
                    shapeGrid.erase(shapeGrid.begin() + x);
                    cout << "Shape Removed" << endl;

            }

            if (conditionmet())
            {
                    shapeGrid.erase(shapeGrid.begin() + x);
                    cout << "Shape Removed" << endl;


            }

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < shapeGrid.size(); i++)  // Shuffle positions
    {
        shapeGrid[i].x = (rand() % 100) + 1;
        shapeGrid[i].y = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you accidentally copy-paste your `conditionmet()` block a second time?

Comment: Suggestion: consider simplification of the task. Imagine you have an **array** (not vector) of integeres and you need to remove all even ones. How would you go about it? This is a very good algo question for learners, but it would do you good to come to a solution yourself.

Comment: if you are going to modify the vector while looping, you should have a look at using iterators instead of `.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you should avoid modifying the dimensions of an array or vector in an iteration/loop- as you risk running into the invalid index issue, or missing items appended at the end.

Rather than removing elements on the vector object as you iterate through it, you should create a new vector object in the iteration process, copying what you want to keep.  Then after the loop, reset/replace the original vector variable with the newly pruned one.

Comment: Use `std::remove` to remove items in place.